# How to set ckeditor height per instance while using knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor with knockout.js and I can't seem to set the instance of the editor per instance.
Here is my code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.CKEDITOR = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
    // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
    var ckEditorValue = valueAccessor();
    var id = $(element).attr('id');
    var options = allBindings().EditorOptions;
    var instance = CKEDITOR.replace(id, {
        on: {
            change: function () {
                ckEditorValue(instance.getData());
            }
        },
        height: 350 // doesn't set the height...
    })
}
```

};

I can use this code inside the init function:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function () {
    if (typeof (options) != 'undefined') {
          viewModel.css({ 'width': options.Width });
          viewModel.find('.cke_contents').css({ 'height': options.Height });
      }
    });
```

But this is called twice as times for each instance... so I need somthing more focused per instance.
Is it possible ?

Comment: It's hard to tell without working example. Your `height: 350` definition for an instance [seems correct](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_size).

Comment: When debugging, I can see that it sets the height to 350 and then it overrides it with an inline style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue like this:

At first, I set an `options` binding for each editor in the html, like so:

```
<textarea data-bind="CKEDITOR: Content, id: '1', EditorOptions: { height: 250, width: 670 }"></textarea>

<textarea id="2" data-bind="CKEDITOR: Content, EditorOptions: { height: 100 }"></textarea>
```

And on the javascript binding handler I have this implementation:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.CKEDITOR = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var ckEditorValue = valueAccessor();
        var id = $(element).attr('id');
        var allBindings = allBindings();

        // this holds the height for each instance
        var options = allBindings.EditorOptions;

        id = (typeof allBindings.id == 'undefined' ? id : allBindings.id);

        $(element).attr('id', id);

        var ignoreChanges = false;

        var defaultConfig = {};
        defaultConfig.toolbar = [
                                    ["Undo", "Redo"],
                                    ["Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "RemoveFormat", "-", "TextColor"],
                                    ["NumberedList", "BulletedList", "Outdent", "Indent"],
                                    ["JustifyLeft", "JustifyCenter", "JustifyRight", "JustifyBlock"],
                                    ["Link", "Unlink"]
                                ];
        defaultConfig.defaultLanguage = 'en';
        defaultConfig.removePlugins = 'resize, wordcount, elementspath, magicline';
        defaultConfig.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

        defaultConfig.on = {
            change: function () {
                ignoreChanges = true;
                ckEditorValue(instance.getData());
                ignoreChanges = false;
            }
        };

        // merge the height with the defaultConfig
        $.extend(defaultConfig, options);

        var instance = CKEDITOR.replace(id, defaultConfig);

        instance.setData(ckEditorValue());

        ckEditorValue.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            if (!ignoreChanges) {
                instance.setData(newValue);
            }
        });
    }
};
```